# Excel: Match Text in Two Columns and Return a Value Relative to Their Intersection

Tags: database, excel

This is working with text, and Excel's If Function doesn't like to return valid responses when checking for text within cell ranges.

I need a single cell to check for possibly repeating text in an array. Whenever it finds that text, it needs to check another column for different text. If it finds that both of those columns contain both text strings, then it needs to return a value in another column to the right of those other two columns.

Example:

```
     A        B       C

1|   Hi  |   Bill  |  25
2|   Do  |   You   |  50
3|  Like |  Cheese |  75
4|   Hi  |   Bill  |  100
```

So, I need a formula that looks for "Hi" in Column A. If it finds "Hi" in Column A, it then looks for "Bill" in Column B. If it finds "Hi" in Column A and "Bill" in Column B, then it returns "100" from Column C.

To top this off, I need this formula to search through the entire array and return only the largest number in Column C for all intersections of "Hi" and "Bill" from Columns A and B. Hence why it'd return "100" and not "25."

Answer (score 1):

You can combine MAX() and IF() and array-enter the formula with Ctrl+Shift+Enter as showed on this website [MAX IF and MIN IF example](http://blog.contextures.com/archives/2011/07/27/finding-min-if-or-max-if-in-excel/).

[image: Excel example of MAX(IF())]

The formula I used is:

```
=MAX(IF(CONCATENATE(A1:A4,",",B1:B4)=CONCATENATE(A6,",",B6),C1:C4))
```

To look for both values you can concatenate them and put a separator between them. Here, I used a comma.

In the formula I reference arrays A1:A4, B1:B4 and C1:C4 that is way once you typed the formula in the cell instead of just pressing enter you need to press Ctrl+Shift+Enter. That will make it an array formula and display the brackets that you can see in my screenshot.